# Characters at the end do not match

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to match all the alphabets and numbers in a string `str`.

This is my code.

```
str.match(/^(AB)(\d+)([A-Za-z][0-9])?/)
```

When `str = AB57933A` [sic], it matches only `AB57933`, and not the characters appended after the numbers.

If I try with `str = AB57933AbC` [sic], it matches only `AB57933`; it only matches up to the last number, and not the characters after that.

Comment: Merge the last two character classes: [`/\A(AB)(\d+)([A-Za-z0-9])?/`](http://rubular.com/r/IyLUgFucuu)

Comment: If I do this I only get 1 character from last my 1 case works but my second case doesn't work. If I provide this it gives me only AB57933A. It is not matching the entire string

Comment: see my answer hereunder! ;-) hope it helps you

Comment: Adding a `+` is not a problem. Still, your requirements are not clear. If you need to match an entire string and the digits/letters at the end are optional, then you need `/\A(AB)(\d+)([A-Za-z0-9]*)\z/`

Comment: @ankur `?` means 0 or 1, `+` means 1 or more and `*` means 0 or more. You can use any depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the way you have written it:

```
/^(AB)(\d+)([A-Za-z][0-9])/
```

you impose that the last character is between `0` and `9`, you can replace it depending on your needs by if you do not expect digits after the last letter

```
/^(AB)(\d+)([A-Za-z]+)/
```

or by

```
/^(AB)(\d+)([A-Za-z0-9]+)/
```

if `AB57933AbC12` are also accepted as valid input.

Last but not least, if you do not use back references you can omit the parenthesis as you do not need capturing groups